# Dymola 2018 performance on Linux (xubuntu)

Tags: modelica, dymola

The issue that I experience is that when running simulations (same IBPSA/AixLib-based models) on Linux I get a significant performance drop (simulation time is about doubled) in comparison to a Windows 8 machine. Below you find the individual specs of the two machines. In both cases I use Cvode solver with equal settings. Compilation is done with VC14.0 (Win) or GCC (Xubuntu).

Is this issue familiar to someone or can anyone help what the reason might be?

Win 8:
Intel Xeon @2.9GHz (6 logic processors)
32 GB RAM
64-Bit

Xubuntu 16.04 VM:
Intel Xeon @3.7GHz (24 logic processors)
64 GB RAM
64-Bit

Thanks!

Comment: You are probably not using MinGW on Linux. Is the Xubuntu a virtual machine? Is Windows using a SSD? Do both simualtions generate the same numer of events? Same translation statistics? Are you using some kind of parallelization? Sparse solver? Is the situation the same with the latest Dymola release?

Comment: Yes you're right, it's gcc. Xubuntu is a virtual machine. I tested some of your suggestions and it actually seems that writing the results is the dominant bottleneck here where a SSD makes the difference.

Comment: You could try to filter the results and only save the relevant variables, thus reducing the file size.

Comment: Usually I only save output variables. But in this case it has only a minor impact on the simulation speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the checklist in the comments, also consider enabling hardware virtualization support if not already done.

In general gcc tends to produce slower code than Visual Studio. In order to turn on optimization one could try adding the following line:

CFLAGS=$CFLAGS" -02"

at the top of insert/dsbuild.sh.

The reason for not having it turned on by default is to avoid lenghty compilations and bloated binaries. For industrial sized models these are actual issues.

Comment: Is this the same as setting Advanced.Define.GlobalOptimizations = 2? Because this I already tried without any impact.

Comment: Advanced.Define.GlobalOptimizations only applies to Visual Studio; gcc has no corresponding unfortunately.

Comment: Setting the CFLAG closed the gap significantly. Results in a speed up of approximately 20 %. Now the performance is at least in the range of a 2.9 GHz Win workstation without SSD. Thanks so far!